# How to reuse DataTable for multiple SqlDataAdapter inserts

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Given a `DataTable` loaded with some data how can it be reused to perform multiple inserts into different SQL Server database tables using different `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` methods?

After using the `DataTable` to insert records into table 1, a different `SqlDataAdapter` will not insert data into table 2 and `Update()` method always returns 0 without throwing an exception.

I tried using the `Copy()` and `RejectChanges()` methods of the `DataTable` but it never inserts data into table 2.

Some code:

```
var dataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter
{
    UpdateBatchSize = updateBatchSize,
    InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertCommand1, dbConnection)
    {
        UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None
    }
};
dataAdapter1 .InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id");  
dbConnection.Open();
dataAdapter1 .Update(dtSomeDataTable);
// This inserts data into table 1.
var dataAdapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter
{
    UpdateBatchSize = updateBatchSize,
    InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertCommand2, dbConnection)
    {
        UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None
    }
};
var count = dataAdapter2.Update(dtSomeDataTable);
//This does not insert any records (or throws an exception) and variable count is always 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by keeping the original `DataTable` unchanged and working on copies for each required update created using the `DataTable.Copy()` method... If a better answer is posted I'll accept that instead...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this MSDN post to understand the concept of DataRow.RowState: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0(v=vs.110).aspx

When you call Update on the first SqlAdapter, all rows are marked as Unchanged and subsequent Update calls won't consider them anymore.

You could try "touching" each row by reading a value from one of the columns and setting that same value. Maybe that will cause the RowState to switch to Modified so that the second Update operation acts on all rows again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try calling SetAdded on each DataRow, before the 2nd call to Update ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.setadded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx